# Automatically open maximized and fit correctly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

Does anyone at all know how to get C# GUI programs to automatically open maximized and fit correctly in whatever screen resolution is on the computer?when I run and maximize the application the **tablepage(Control)** is not maximize and as well as other controls.please help me with details...

Answer (score 2):

Use the `WindowState` property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate(v=vs.110).aspx

Set the property to `Maximized` before you show the form.

If you want your controls to resize with the window, use the `Anchor` and `Dock` properties in the Forms Designer.

Use `Anchor` to have a control's edge be a fixed distance from a given edge, and use the `Dock` property to have a control fill an area.

Comment: but in tabpage control there is no Anchor Property :(

Comment: Use the "Document Outline" panel to select the `TabControl` control, not `TabPage`, TabPages don't have set dimensions: they fill their parent TabControl.